# How do I mongoexport attributes from an array of objects to CSV?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, csv

I need to export values of objects in an array to CSV. Let's say my document is:

```
{
    name:"test",
    types:[
        {type:"A"},
        {type:"B"},
                {type:"C"}
    ]
}
```

My goal is to produce output like:

```
"test", "A"
"test", "B"
"test", "C"
```

The following would also be acceptable:

```
"test", "A,B,C"
```

I'm trying to accomplish this via mongoexport using:

```
mongoexport -h localhost -d mydb -c mycollection -f name,types.type --csv
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting:

```
"test",
```

I've found documentation on referencing specific array elements, like "types.0.type", but the length of my array is unknown. Any ideas?

Comment: I have the exact same scenario.  I would rather not write a custom script to handle this, because I want the primary responsibility to be on our data analysts (who can run mongoexport) rather than my development team. Were you able to find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write a custom script that iterates through collections and exports documents in desired format. Built-in mongoexport was not designed for use cases like yours.

Answer (score 1):

If your happy with **Perl** then the ARJsonLib.pm library in the following [article](http://www.experts-exchange.com/A_10413.html), provides the majority of functionality you'll need, to create your own little toy. Note the version in the article is a stub from a toy I hacked together that does exactly what you want along with some other stuff, but as not a mongoDB article it's lacking one function you'll need, that finds the fields/keys in a mongoDB collection, and stores them in an array, but trivial to reconstruct, just write yourself something that pull's *n* documents from your collection, pushes them into an array and calls findKeysInJsonColl(). Anyway a couple of the functions will take a MongoDB cursor as parameter, and:

```
convertToDojoGrid()
convertToExcel()
```

Again the **CSV** output is missing, but trivial to add back to convertToExcel().

e.g.

```
...
my $iRows  = convertToExcel("/tmp/test.xlsx", $oMongoData, "", \@aOutFields, "xlsx");
...
```

Where: $oMongoData  is a MongoDB Cursor reference and @aOutFields an array containing the fields/keys you wish to appear in the sheet,

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what your are trying to do by using the MongoDb's aggregation pipeline operations to build out a temporary collection with the data in the shape you want to export:

```
use mydb
db.mycollection.aggregate([ 
                          {$unwind: "$types"}, 
                          {$project: { _id: 0, name: 1, type: "$types.type" } }, 
                          {$out: "tmp4csv"} 
                          ]);
```

this will create a tmp4csv collection which contains a document for each element of the array

i.e in your example (and adding a _id value as this value has to be taken into consideration in my suggested solution)

```
{   
    _id: ObjectId("54e3ce75cb87e6d036287cc6"),
    name:"test",
    types:[
        {type:"A"},
        {type:"B"},
        {type:"C"}
        ]
}
```

through the use of the $unwind operator becomes

```
{ _id: ObjectId("54e3ce75cb87e6d036287cc6"), name:"test", types:[ {type:"A"} ] },
{ _id: ObjectId("54e3ce75cb87e6d036287cc6"), name:"test", types:[ {type:"B"} ] },
{ _id: ObjectId("54e3ce75cb87e6d036287cc6"), name:"test", types:[ {type:"C"} ] }
```

Next the $project operator is used to reform the data slightly - unpacking types.type into type and providing a new unique _id value for each document.

Finally the documents generated by the aggregation pipeline are output in to the "tmp4csv" collection using the $out operator. Without the creation of a unique _id value in the previous step this step would fail due to duplicate keys.

You can then export the data to an output file:

```
mongoexport -h localhost -d mydb -c tmp4csv -f name,type --csv --out output.csv
```

And to keep everything clean I would then drop the tmp4csv collection that was created as part of this:

```
use mydb
db.tmp4csv.drop()
```

This should give you a csv file with your preferred output format.

References:
Aggregation pipeline doc: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/
Unwind operator as this is key: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/